# spikes coming out of donut mesh after doing bump

Tags: bump

[image]

This happened when I tried to do bumps on my mesh. Do anyone know how til fix it? Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: you need to be in Cycles, in the Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement you need to choose Displacement Only and also you need to be in Rendered mode if you want to see a real displacement

Comment: Thanks :) But when I did that the mesh got spikes coming out if. I have attached a picture of it in the post - do you know how I can fix that? :)

Comment: Lower the *Scale* value of the *Displacement* node. The spikes should be bumps but the scale is too high.